# Notation confusion in the Wikipedia article on the Law of Large Numbers

Tags: probability, statistics, notation

In my infamous attempt at mastering (at my humble level) the "art" of probability and statistical theory, I was reading the Wikipedia article on the [Law of Large Number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_large_numbers#Forms) and got confused by a couple of notations.

1 - mean vs expected value

First it is written:

$\bar X \rightarrow \mu$ for $n \rightarrow \infty$

For me $\mu$ is the "population" mean and not the expected value. The definition of the law is that the sample mean converges to the random variable expected value as the sample size approaches infinity (not its population mean). I realize the population mean and the expected value are equal but they are not computed the same way and I found this notation misleading (because it doesn't follow directly the definition). What do you think?

2 - random variable vs observation

Second it is written:

$\bar X = {1 \over n}(X_1 + X_2 + ... + X_n)$

"where X1, X2, ... is an infinite sequence of i.i.d. integrable random variables with expected value $E(X1) = E(X2) = ...= \mu$."

Why I am confused is that for me the sample mean is computed as the average of n observation where the observations are produced by a random variable X. So it would be for me at least less misleading to use x lower case (observation, realization) instead of X uppercase. Or is correct here to use X and if so why?

EDIT: I understand you need to write $E[X_1]$ and can't write $E[x_1]$. The expected value of an observation wouldn't make much sense. But that what's the meaning really of $X_n$ in $\bar X = {1 \over n}(X_1 + X_2 + ... + X_n)$. For me a random variable is a function not really a number? An average of functions?

But I am not an expert so there might be an explanation to both notations? Thank you.

Comment: 1. "Mean" and "expected value" here mean the same thing. "Sample mean" is different.
2. $\overline X$ is a random variable. In the strict sense, random variables are functions from the sample space to $\mathbb R$. They can be manipulated algebraically pointwise. That means $\overline{X}(\omega) = \frac 1n\sum_{i=1}^n X_i(\omega)$ for $\omega \in \Omega$, $\Omega$ being the sample space.

Comment: @Tunococ Sorry I wasn't referring to the mean actually but to the population mean. And population mean and EV are equal but not computed the same way. So I think using $\mu$ which is the symbol for population mean in place of the expected value is misleading. But thanks for 2).

Comment: @Tunococ just to be clear you write $\bar X(\omega)={1\over n}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i(\omega)$. Simple minded as I am for me this is the same as writing f(x) = g(x) + h(x). So if $\omega$ is the same for each random variable, shouldn't they map to the same value from $\mathbb{R}$? sorry it's very confusing to me... it's almost if you would prefer to write $\bar X={1\over n}\sum_{i=1}^n X(\omega_i)$? please help. Where I left the sample mean intentionally as not being defined as some sort of function of $\omega$.

Comment: $X_1$ and $X_2$ are different functions.

Comment: They are but they have the same probability distribution?!

Comment: They have the same marginal distribution. For example, let's say $X_i$ can take on values from the set $S$. For a given $n$, we can make up the sample space $\Omega = S^n$, and let $X_i(\omega) = \pi_i(\omega)$ where $\pi: S^n \to S$ is the projection of the $i$-th factor. Depending on the probability measure, $X_i$ may be i.i.d. even when they are obviously different functions from $\Omega$ to $S$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, in statistics, "mean value" and "expected value" are synonyms: [see here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value).

Second, the notations in mathematics are quite flexible (there're some standard notations, of course; real numbers are always $\Bbb R$, for example) in terms of how you call your variables. You can write them in uppercase, lowercase, greek or latin alphabet, sometimes we use hebrew and cyrillic symbols (might have missed something, I suppose). You are free to introduce your own conventions of notations, and they don't necessarily coincide with the notations on wiki. As a personal example, in Russia it's quite common to note Lebesgue spaces as $L_p$, while in international literature the standard notation is $L^p$.

In your particular example, you note your variables in uppercase latin, so in my opinion it's logical to note the result of arithmetic operations over them in the same uppercase latin, to reinforce that this result retains the same nature as the terms in the sum. To illustrate, one of common notations for linear algebra uses lowercase latin for vectors and lowercase greek for scalars to underline that these two entities have different nature.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you. While I appreciate your answer I would disagree. Mean and expected value are equal but are not computed the same way. If that's what you mean by synonymous then fine. But when mathematicians claim you to need to be precise in your definition and notation and use one word in the definition and use a symbol meaning another word later, then sorry but this is not perfect. As for your second point I understand your argument. However in one case one speaks of realisations and in the other of function (r.v.). Two different things!

Comment: Okay I understand where the confusion between mean and expected value comes from. I am not talking about the words I am talking about the symbols E[X] or EV and $\mu$. $\mu$ is the population mean not the mean. So I am saying they use the symbol for population mean not the expected value.

Comment: Could you elaborate on `Mean and expected value are equal but are not computed the same way.`? I don't quite get how we can calculate $\Bbb E\xi$ in many different ways=)

Comment: sorry as I said I made mistake I meant to say population mean (denoted usually with symbol $\mu$) and expected value. For me population mean is equal to simple average of all the elements in the population (without weighting). EV is equal sum of outcomes weighted by their probability. Numbers are the same (equal) but there's a slight difference in the "semantic".

Comment: I think they just used this notation not bearing in mind that in statistics this letter could be a stadard notation for something similar yet different. The wiki article you quoted doesn't have the word `population` in it. After all, $\mu$ is quite "charged" letter; it's a measure, population mean (as I've just learned), chemical potential, and it's only a start=).

Comment: True I agree but since there's a notation for expected value which is E[X] as you point out in the article from wiki on the expected value you will notice it uses E[X] everywhere and not $\mu$.;-)

Comment: Ah but to make things worse in the article on the "mean" then they use $\mu$ to compute the mean from probability. Terrible.

Comment: At this point my advice is to not be overzealous with notations and with enforcing your notation conventions; after all it's strange to give one meaning to a symbol once and never allow other usages. It's equally strange to not accept different notations for the same thing (bar well-known exceptions like $\pi$, $e$, etc).

Comment: I would disagree with that, but I understand different people can have different conventions. Standardisation is extremely important for lots of obvious reasons. In my case learning and avoiding to be confused is one. Try to go in class and tell you teacher something is on the left when it's on the right because you decided to interchanged left and right (not assuming you are dyslexic) and not only you might cause a mess but you will have bad marks. Word have a meaning so should have symbols ;-). Again I understand the difficulty of enforcing this (and the risk of doing so).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/10777/discussion-between-tzakrevskiy-and-marc-ourens)